# Find least number of divisors to satisfy conditions

Tags: number-theory

Given an integer $N$ such that all divisors  of $N $ are

$\equiv 1 \mod8$  $\quad$ or

$ \equiv 3 \mod 8$

What is the least number of  distinct prime divisors so that $I(N)\ge2$, where $I(N)= \frac{\sigma(N)}{N}$.

So far I got that $\frac{11}{10} \cdot \frac{17}{16} \cdot \frac{19}{18} \cdot \frac{41}{40} \cdot \frac{43}{42} \cdot \frac{59}{58} \cdot \frac{67}{66} \cdot \frac{73}{72} \approx 
1.35547339964597027526$ , so it seems like there is a long way to go.

Comment: What is $I(N)$?